# Error in wordpress customizr theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

yesterday I installed  customizr theme and after turning it on my site crashed and i'm receiving error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting ',' or ')' in /wp-content/themes/customizr/core/functions.php on line 3152
```

Here's the mentioned line:

```
else if ( class_exists($cb[0]) && isset($cb[0]::$instance) && method_exists($cb[0]::$instance, $cb[1]) ) {
    $to_return = call_user_func( array( $cb[0]::$instance ,  $cb[1] ), $params );
```

I will be really gratefull if someone could fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Few things I found disturbing in your code, I dont know what these are representing so I would go with my instance.

1) you are calling `method_exists` with static variable as first argurment, it should be class name, in your case only `$cb[0]`.

2) while calling `call_user_func` you are again passing static variable. What should come here as first argument depends upon you class structure. Any way I think  `call_user_func( array( $cb[0],  $cb[1] ), $params );` should work